# Ionic Storage delivers undefined value

Tags: angular, storage, ionic2

How I can use the Ionic Storage within my application. I tried with the following, but when I try to read out I get always `[object Object]` as value back. It works when I have the get/set method in one class, but I want structure my project and outsource the storage part.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'page-login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    export class LoginPage {

      constructor(public testData: TestData) {}

      onLogin(form) { 

        if (form.valid) {
          this.testData.setTestParam("abc");
          console.log("Stored: " +   this.testData.getTestParam()) ;
          // delivers => Stored: [object Object]
        }
    }
```

**TestData Class**

```
@Injectable()
export class TestData {

 constructor(public storage : Storage) {}

 setTestParam(testparam) 
 {
   this.storage.set('test_param', testparam);
 }

 getTestParam(){
   return this.storage.get('test_param').then((value) => {
      return value;
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: If you are in chrome go to your debug console and in to your Application tab and see how the data is saved under WebSQL or whichever driver was used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getTestParam()` returns a promise not the value.
You can read the value by doing

```
this.testData.getTestParam().then(data=>{
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: I have to do this in my LoginPage Class?

Comment: yes..in place of `  console.log("Stored: " +   this.testData.getTestParam()) ;`

Comment: Thanks, works. Is this the proper way, or would you recommend something other?

Comment: this is the way to get value from a promise

Comment: whats the alternate? is there are shorter way? looks much code for me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: When I doing in this way, it shows not the current saved value, it always show the value which got saved before. Do you know why ?

Comment: depends on where you are setting again

Comment: I mean, i did like you showed above, but it returns always the old stored value. Not the latest set value.

Comment: oh..ok.. right the storage.set method also returns a promise..both are asynchronous..you will have ti make sure you do get from storage after set.then

Comment: Could please show me how the set.then method looks ? Would be greatful.

Comment: this.storage.set(key,value).then(()=>{//do something});

Comment: But what I actually should do in this part (do something) ?  I could do the storage.get within this, but I actually dont need in in this moment.

Comment: if you need to execute any code only after storing (synchronous execution) you will have to do there

Answer (score 1):

you can use this hope it will help you .

```
@Component({
      selector: 'page-login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    export class LoginPage {

      constructor(public testData: TestData) {}

      onLogin(form) { 
        if (form.valid) {
          this.testData.setTestParam("abc");
          this.testData.getTestParam().then((value: any) => {
           console.log(value);
           });
           }}}
```

TestData Class

```
@Injectable()
export class TestData {

 constructor(public storage : Storage) {}

 setTestParam(testparam) 
 {
   this.storage.set('test_param', testparam);
 }

 getTestParam(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.storage.get('test_param').then((value) => {
                resolve(value);
            });
        });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `getTestParam` return a Promise instead of a normal value. In order to read the return value from Promise, you should use `then` method and use `catch` method to handle any error.